# Java Swing Change Icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe

Is it possible to change the coffee cup icon that is displayed when switching applications (command+tab) on a mac or (alt+tab) on windows?

I am not referring to the icon in the Jframe window border.

Comment: AFAIK they're the same thing, aren't they? Correct me if I'm wrong, though, I've never really paid too much attention to it.

Comment: @Brian I agree with you, AFAIK, at least under Windows 7, it seems to work fine...

Comment: I tried  this.setIconImage(STANDARD_ICON); and it did not change the icon shown when switching apps. - I am on a mac

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11253772/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exporting the jar as a Mac OS X bundle. It is an option in eclipse under other. As you do that it will prompt you to pick an icns file for an icon that is used for the program bundle and dock icon.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Windows 8 and My JFrame gives the Icon I defined in the contructor, here is the code and the pic of the result it shows,

```
this.setIconImage(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("images\\icon.png").getImage());
```

This line is placed in constructor of the class which extends JFrame, Maybe it does'nt help you but It's working with me, Remember the URl I gave for the Image is relative. Here is the Image of the result.

[image]

Comment: It did not work on the mac unfortunately. I still see the coffeecup.

Comment: Ohh Sorry, but unfortunately I cannot help you more.