# How to set an icon image for an application?

Tags: java, macos

When I start my application, the icon on the desktop looks like this:

[image: Default Logo for a Java application.]

I want to know if there is a way I can change that image to an image of my choosing?

Comment: yes but depends on ide for the steps to take. What are you using eclipse?

Comment: @DerekLawrence Yes, I am using Eclipse.

Comment: You might want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279556/4039840)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("logo.png")).getImage()
```

This works when the image is in the same package as the class.
Note: It is better to have images in a resource folder

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIO.read(new File("res/game.png")));
```

where res/game.png is the icon image you want to use

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html