# Replacing the java file icon

Tags: java

I want to replace my runnable JAR file icon (the coffee icon) with my chosen icon, will I use third party software to attain it or it can be done on the source code of the JAR file? Any how?

EDIT:

I have use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to do this:D

Comment: i am not sure this could help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590885/how-to-change-executable-jar-file-icon

Comment: thank you for the link, found an answer in the Answer section :D

Comment: my pleasure welcome