# Including image Icons in executable jar file

Tags: java, image, swing, jar, embedded-resource

I'm making a Chess Game, and I've got it up an running pretty well, but I want to be able to export it as a JAR file for ease of use. but when I export it the Icons of the chesspieces that I put on the JButtons aren't there. My images are stored in a seperate folder calles Images in the same level as the src and JRE System Library. ive tried using the `getClass().getResource(string)` method but it gives me a null pointer exception. ive tried the answers in articles asking similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483283/set-icon-image-in-jar-file). but to no avail

Comment: The jar should contain the icons. By putting them outside of the src directory and using the basic export functions of your IDE, the images were probably not included in the jar file. A jar file is just a zip file, so open it, and see if they're present and in which package. But really, since they're resources that must be loaded by the ClassLoader just like class files, they should be in some package under the src directory (or any other directory that is a source folder in your IDE project)

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: As a (lighter download, more versatile) alternative to images for chess pieces, consider rendering them at run-time from the Unicode glyphs - as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18686753/418556).

Comment: Try this 2 links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file

Comment: Are you sure the icons are in your jar file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you pass an incorrect resource name, and since the class loader can't find it, `getResource()` will return `null`.

`Class.getResource(String name)` expects a resource name *relative* to the location the class is loaded from. So if your resource is called `image.jpg`, then `image.jpg` must be in the same folder where the class is whose `getResource()` method you're calling.

You can also specify an absolute folder inside the jar if you start it with the `/` character:

```
getClass().getResource("/resources/images/image.jpg");
```

In this case the `image.jpg` must be in the `/resources/images` folder inside the jar or in your source folder (which will be copied to the `bin` folder by your IDE).

You can also navigate up one (or more) folder compared to the folder of the class with the `".."` literal, e.g.:

```
getClass().getResource("../images/image.jpg");
```

In this case the `image.jpg` file must be in the `images` subfolder of the parent folder compared to the folder of the class.

**Note:** The `Class` object whose `getResource()` method you call can be acquired like `YourClassName.class` or if you want to refer to the class of the current instance: `getClass()`.